# Show image in html depending on typescript info ionic angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am pulling some user profile data from the database and storing it in an observable.
I can access properties with typing `profileData.username`,`profileData.msgnumber` etc...

`profileData.avatar` returns the name of avatar user is using. What I'm trying to do is if `profileData.avatar` equals "bear" display bear picture in HTML or if it equals "spider" display spider in HTML. Now I can display just string by writing `{{profileData.avatar}}`

Comment: what have you tried so far? give some example JSON for `profileData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ionic 2 you need to write something like,

```
<ion-item>
 <ion-avatar>
  <img src=" {{profileData.avatar}}">
 </ion-avatar>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: im not holding avatars with urls.they are just strings. like avatar:"bear" is there any other way ?

Comment: Just a string 'bear' will not work for getting image and display it in html file. Absolute or relative any path of image would be needed.